# Making a KeyListener?

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I'm trying to make a KeyEventListener but it never prints anything. I already have a main class, do I need to "register" or something?

```
    package client;

    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

    public class KeyEventListener implements KeyListener
    {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0)
        {       
            System.out.print("HI1");        
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
        {       
            System.out.print("HI2");        
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0)
        {       
            System.out.print("HI3");        
        }   
    }
```

Comment: The javadoc should _always_ be your first place to look (before asking a question). Consult the Javadoc for `KeyListener` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) and look at the second paragraph

Comment: Quick google search results in this [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Answer (score 2):

- AWT/Swing Component must be focusable or focus owner in window, otherwise never to react to the Key Events, and Top-Level Containers too
- don't to use KeyListener without important reasons e.g. three or more keys are presses in the same time, e.i.
- for Swing to use KeyBindings instead, because KeyListener isn't designated for Swing JComponents or caused a few side effects in compare with KeyBindings
- more informations, inc. working code examples in Oracle tutorial, seach here for additional details or detailed descriptions
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable